# If oracle table1 is empty then output table2 else output table1 itself; No columns on both the tables are common

Tags: oracle

I have two different table:
Table1, Table2.

Two tables have different columns and nothing in common. What I am looking to get is
 if Table1 is empty/null then
 output Table2
else
 output table1

Is it possible to get it done in Oracle? Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a table named dual in your sql server? That is an oracle thing. And I am not at all clear what you want to do here.

Comment: Seems really odd that you have a table named `dual` with a column called `sysdate` in SQL Server.  Both of those are associated with Oracle.  Your query makes no sense because `column1` and `column2` are not defined.  Sample data and desired results could help rescue the question.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I have made amendments to the question. I hope it is not confusing now. I tried using EXISTS, NOT EXISTS, NULL, NOT NULL. But nothing is helping me get the requested answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to your phrase:

> if Table1 is empty/null then output Table2 else output table1

I think the solution is (I briefed Table1, Table2 by A, B respectively ):

```
--I created this tables to test the solution
create table A( id number, val varchar2(5));
create table B( code varchar2(5), event_dt date);

insert into b(code, event_dt)
  values ('test', sysdate);
--query(1)
select b.code, to_char(b.event_dt,'yyyy-mm-dd') 
  from b
 where not exists (select 1 from a)
union 
 select to_char(id), to_char(val)
   from a
; 
--now insert data on the other table (to test purposes)
insert into A(id, val)
  values(1, 'TestA');

--run the query(1) again
```

The key is "union", kind of repeat your query when the first portion deals to no data 
  found.
  Please remember to CAST your columns to achieve the same DATA-TYPES required by UNION

Best regards.

Comment: Then please, qualify the answer as "correct answer", and "useful", have a great day